# Boto: Update file in s3 keep permissions

Tags: boto

I am trying to update a text file stored in s3 but keep its permissions, here is my code.

```
def update(key, str):
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    b = s3.get_bucket('bucket')
    k = bucket.get_key(key)

    acl = k.get_acl()
    k.set_contents_from_string(str)
    k.set_acl(acl)
```

The error I get is as follows.

```
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>     
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have also tried

```
k.set_contents_from_string(str, policy=acl)
```

What is the correct way to update/replace a file but keep the original files permissions.

Comment: When do you get that error?  On the ``set_contents_from_string`` call?  If that's the case, I don't think it has anything to do with trying to set the ACL.  It just looks like the credentials you are using don't have permission to write to the bucket.

Comment: I got the same issue. Waiting for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
key.set_contents_from_string(str, policy='public-read', headers={'Content-Type': "something"})
```

Comment: Please add more than just code as your answer. I have marked this answer as "looks okay", but it is recommended that you add some explanation.